# Obtener filas que tengan relación con otra tabla solo si se cumplen todas las relaciones

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

**item**

```
   |------|--------|--------|
   |  id  |  name  |  desc  |
   |------|--------|--------|
   |  1   |  gato  |  rtre  |
   |------|--------|--------|
   |  2   |lagarto |  gte   |
   |------|--------|--------|
   |  3   | aguila |   rre  |
   |------|--------|--------|
```

**category**

```
   |------|----------|
   |  id  |   name   |
   |------|----------|
   |   1  | mamifero |
   |------|----------|
   |   2  |  reptil  |
   |------|----------|
   |   3  |   ave    |
   |------|----------|
   |   4  |  oviparo |
   |------|----------|
   |   5  | terrestre|
   |------|----------|
```

**category_item**

```
   |---------|---------|
   | item_id |  cat_id |
   |---------|---------|
   |   1     |    1    |
   |---------|---------|
   |   1     |    5    |
   |---------|---------|
   |   2     |    2    |
   |---------|---------|
   |   2     |    4    |
   |---------|---------|
   |   2     |    5    |
   |---------|---------|
   |   3     |    3    |
   |---------|---------|
   |   3     |    4    |
   |---------|---------|
```

Por ejemplo, si quiero obtener todos los animales de pertenecen a la categoria *terrestre* y *mamifero* y  hago algo así:

```
SELECT citem.*
FROM `category_item` AS ci 
INNER JOIN `item` AS citem 
ON citem.id = ci.item_id 
WHERE ci.cat_id IN (1,5)
```

pero eso me trae como resultado **gato** y **lagarto**.

Lo que quiero lograr es obtener los registros que tengan ambas categorias y no solo una de ellas. Como resultado debria obtener **gato**

Un detalle más, quisiera que la consulta me devolviera las coincidencias entre varias categorias con un categoria constante, es decir: seleccionar los items que tengan la categoria **terrestre** y **mamifero** pero tambien las que tengan **terrestre** y **reptil** y asi sucesivamente. Si hubiera más items que tuvieran relacion con **terrestre** y otra categoria más tambien deberian mostrarse.

Intenté lo siguiente:

```
SELECT citem.*
FROM `category_item` AS ci 
INNER JOIN `item` AS citem 
ON citem.id = ci.item_id 
WHERE ci.cat_id IN (1,2)
AND ci.cat_id = 5
```

pero no me devuelve ninguna fila. Ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes lograrlo agrupando los resultados y usando la clausula `HAVING` asi:

```
SELECT citem.*
FROM `category_item` AS ci 
INNER JOIN `item` AS citem 
ON citem.id = ci.item_id 
WHERE ci.cat_id IN (1,5)
GROUP BY ci.item_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: funciona pero creo que cometí un error y hay un detalle que no mencioné,  quisiera que la consulta me devolviera las coincidencia entre varias categorias con un categoria cosntante, es decir: seleccionar los items que tengan la categoria **terrestre** y **mamifero** pero tambien las que tengan    **terrestre** y **reptil** y asi sucesivamente, si hubiera más items que tuvieran relacion con **terrestre** y otra categoria más

Answer (score 0):

prueba con esta:

```
 SELECT it.name
 FROM category_item ci
 INNER JOIN item it ON it.id=ci.item_id
 INNER JOIN category ca ON ca.id=ci.cat_id
 WHERE ca.id IN (1,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ejecuta esta sentencia:

```
select i.* from item i 
inner join (
select count(*), item_id from category_item ci
where cat_id in (5,1) 
group by item_id having COUNT(*) = 2) as ci on i.id=ci.item_id
```

Saludos

Comment: no funcionó la consulta

Comment: Probar nuevamente @ReneLimon falto el `as ci `